# What are the implications of "starting up with tabs/windows from last time"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, tails, whonix

I am a bit of a tabs nut, and have been trying to read up on various parts of staying anonymous but where I am the ISP is owned by the gov (relatives of the pres) and they don't like the whole idea of people being anonymous soooo (this is going somewhere) I have been trying to read up somewhat incognito using the TBB but I gotta say its not the most convenient way (for me) to go through lots of material. I usually have lots of tabs open and use a addon (in my none tor bb browser) to manage tabs etc which helps me organize my reading etc.

Question is (are):

1. in a country as small as mine with limited tor usage how visible would I be making myself using 1-2 extra addons?
2. If opening up tor with tabs from last time is that problematic (which i assume it is since it is totally disabled in tor bb) is there some sort of work around? Like these external bookmarking programs, except for tabs? Something similar to "[Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl?hl=en)" (for chrome) but as a separate program that wouldn't been seen my websites that I'd be browsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you stay away from using tabs that persist between application starts. (As well, it's best to not use any additional addons in TBB).

There are different implementations, but often tabs that reopen between browser starts and stops (i.e.: starting and shutting down your browser) will actually make a new request to the server at startup to refresh the open tab.

### Work arounds

The best way to review the data you've accessed over Tor is to download and save it. You can do this on to an encrypted drive for maximum security(*). Since the web pages you download will often contain links or other calls to other network resources, for maximum safety I would only open/view the saved documents on a machine with networking disabled.

(*) The Tails Tor distribution helps make this easier.

Comment: Thanks, thats a really useful idea that I honestly hadn't considered. I haven't used tails that much, your description sounds something like a local app version of Pocket/Instapaper/Readability? (httptrack?). Do you know of a page specifically detailing more info about how tails makes this easier? Do you happen to know if Whonix makes it easier as well?

Comment: Information about tails is at https://tails.boum.org
The instructions provided are intended to be easy to follow for most technically comfortable users. If you have difficulties please let the Tails developers know as it is in everyone's interest to make that installation as simple as possible. Whonix vs. Tails is a whole other question - http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1814/what-are-the-differences-between-tails-and-whonix